# Why is jQuery animate not working with html overflow set to hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Why is my one page navigation not working when i set my html element's overflow property to set? I really like that feature of hidden overflow but its not letting my scroll navigation to work properly.

If you remove the overflow property from the html tag in css my jquery animation seems to no longer work.

My navigation is meant to animate smoothly not jump. See link.

https://jsbin.com/cakuna/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you have no need to add `overflow:auto` in body. you should use `overflow:hidden` here.

Comment: Not sure i get you there? If i use overflow hidden on body i cant scroll trough the page at all?